# Are certain parts of startup scripts necessary or just good practice?

Tags: configuration, init-script, startup

I'm currently exploring creating a startup script in the form of a system process located in the /etc/init.d/ on my Fedora 14 Linux installation. It sounds like the following two lines are bare minimum requirements?

```
#!/bin/bash
# chkconfig: 345 85 15 (however on this one I've seen different combos)
```

What's the purpose of these lines?  Is there a good resource that would help me understand how to better create these and other header lines for such a file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the docs file  `/usr/share/doc/initscripts-*/sysvinitfiles` (On current F14, `/usr/share/doc/initscripts-9.12.1/sysvinitfiles`). There's further documentation here: http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging/SysVInitScript.

The chkconfig line defines which runlevels the service will start in by default (if any), and where in the startup process they'll be ordered.

```
# chkconfig: <startlevellist> <startpriority> <endpriority>

        Required.  <startlevellist> is a list of levels in which
        the service should be started by default.  <startpriority>
        and <endpriority> are priority numbers.  For example:
        # chkconfig: 2345 20 80
```

And, note that this all becomes obsolete with Fedora 15 and `systemd`.

Answer (score 3):

The first line is the "[she-bang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29)" and is used to execute the script without having to pass it as an argument to a shell command line. The second line is a comment and is understood only by the [`chkconfig`](http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.1/Deployment_Guide/s1-services-chkconfig.html) program. It is used to ensure the script will start on a specific run-level.

Comment: To clarify a little more: the `#!` (shebang) line is necessary at the top of any script. The `# chkconfig` is a comment and has no influence on the execution of the script; it's used only by the administration program `chkconfig`.